# Where does map-reduce/hadoop come in in machine learning training?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, machine-learning

Map-reduce/hadoop is perfect in gathering insights from piles of data from various resources, and organize them in a way we want it to be.

But when it comes to training, my impression is that we have to dump all the training data into algorithm (be it SVN, Logistic regression, or random forest) all at once so that the algorithm is able to come up with a model that has it all. Can map-reduce/hadoop help in the training part? If yes, how in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There are many MapReduce implementations such as hadoop streaming and even some easy tools like Pig, which can be used for learning. In addition, there are distributed learning toolset built upon Map/Reduce such as vowpal wabbit (https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial). The big idea of this kind of methods is to do training on small portion of data (split by HDFS) and then averaging the models and commutation with each nodes. So the model get updates directly from submodels built on part of the data.